# Any trick to mark answers as favorites, not just questions?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

We can mark questions as favourites, but usually I would rather want to mark an answer as a favourite. Afaik this is not possible.

In my profile I could check my upvotes, but there I seem to have only limited means of sorting (no answers only or by reverse time).

Am I missing something obvious? Is there some cute trick to effectively mark answers as favourites?

Comment: This meta question seems to belong to the [mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this is not specific to Phys.SE.

Comment: [Previous proposal of this feature on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/) (marked status-declined).