# How to SAVE an answer to a specific question?

Tags: support, answers, bookmarks

I would like to save an Answer to a Question on Physics and any other StackExchange site. Is that possible?

In fact it would REALLY convenient to have a save answer button that lead to a notebook page where I can review all the saved answers, as a reminder and a learning tool.

Comment: Just favourite it using the star below the downvote button.

Comment: @Phase then how'll you access it afterwards? And that's available only for questions not answers.

Comment: @Phase That should be an answer, not a comment. (And you can access favorited questions from your profile.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10240/2451

Comment: Also relevant: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9933/44126

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Prnt Sc ... :P

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no option to directly save answers in any SE site.

What you can do is that, copy the link to the question and save it somewhere, with the name of the user whose answer you want to look at later.

Comment: You can skip that last bit by just saving the direct link to the answer. It's available through the `share` button at the bottom.